# creating multiple canvas to display three.js scene in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 title = 'ang12';
 ngOnInit(): void {
   //const container = document.createElement('div')
  const container = document.getElementById("canvas1");
   document.body.appendChild(container)
   container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
   animate()
 }
}
```

Above the @Component I have all of my three.js code which runs fine it just takes up the entire screen currently. I want to be able to display it on a canvas and move the canvas around. (note I used div tags correctly in the app.component.html) I have also tried just modifying the div style but that doesn't work either

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   const container = document.createElement('div')
   container.style.width = "1000px"
   container.style.top = '5000px';
   document.body.appendChild(container)
   container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
   animate()
 }
}
```

Comment: how large is your screen? 5000px is alot so no surprise it takes space

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether I understand your question, however, I am taking away from it that you would not like your canvas to take up your entire screen.

I would recommend wrapping your canvas in a div within your HTML:

```
<div class="canvas_container">
  <canvas class="webgl_canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Add the following CSS to each element:

```
.canvas_container {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

.webgl_canvas {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

Query select both elements:
*** A much more Angular approach would be to use @ViewChild - I would recommend this.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.canvas_container');
const canvas    = document.querySelector('.webgl_canvas');
```

Make your renderer size the same height and width as the parent div.

```
const sizes = {
  width:  container.clientWidth,
  height: container.clientHeight
};

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 1, 1000);
scene.add(camera);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
});
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
```